# Raw/formatted links/icons missing from some suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I was doing my community service for SO and reviewing suggested edits when I noticed that I couldn't see the "raw" version of an edit because the links were gone:

[image]

(Note that it's only on this particular suggested edit, and not the other ones showing up on the screen)

It was [initially seen on this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/31757) but now [I'm also seeing here](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/31755).  I don't see anything in particular that makes these edits special, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, looking at the two edits in question I think I *might* have just figured out the answer.  There's no markdown formatting because those two edits are title/tag edits only.  Gonna guess this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) but I'll let someone confirm.